# Import VS Connect live for SQL Server analysis Services

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

After setting up my ETL, now I'm preparing the reporting phase. I want to know the diffrence between Import and Connect live a SQL Server analysis Services database methods knowing that I'll be working with measures.

In my example : I need to create a measure which count the emails with failed status by department.

I have (after importing the cube) :

- Fact Mailing Count
- Mail Status Dimension
- Message Template Dimension (having the application name which is the
  same name of the department)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Live connect:** This will connect power bi to analysis services data model directly.so you will be building your model completely on analysis services project and deploying it frequently. So the power bi will have a live connection to the model and make updates when necessary. when new data processed or new measures or tables created. Here the limitation is you cannot combine multiple sources of data and you have to rely on the SASS Model you have already connected with.

**Import:** This will import tables to the Power bi and you will be allowed to create and manipulate your facts and dimensions as per your wish inside the power bi(in live connect mode you have to do it in analysis services model itself). 
The main obstacle of import mode is When you import large tables will a large number of data, power bi has limitations(1GB) on that.

Creating measures and calculated tables are allowed in both modes.the difference is on which side you create them.

A detailed comparison of both Live connect and Import
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Power-BI-Live-connection-vs-Import-comparison-and-limitations/ba-p/84377